What is this Movie from 70s maybe made for tv or pilot
I have started watching the Kolchak series again, and it made me remember what I THINK was a Darren McGavin film or television pilot.
The main detective guy was the McGavin like character. Each segment began with part of a poem or limerick...part of it may have included something like,
“There was a man, who it turns...out to have opened a can of worms.”
I distinctly remember asking my parents what a photographic memory was or something like that, because the character was flipping pages and somehow they showed his ability to recall the pages.
Any ideas? It may NOT have been Darren McGavin. I thought for years the lead in Where Have All the People Gone was David Soul...the internet disavowed me of that false memory.

Found it. The Delphi Bureau: https://www.google.com/amp/www.tv.com/amp/shows/the-delphi-bureau/
There is even discussion of the original limerick used between commercial breaks  but removed from re-issue on DVD.
